# In C++ is really a "reference" just an alias, instead of a "pointer"?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

This code:

```
int main()
{
    int v[] = {0,10,45};

    for (auto& x : v) {
        cout << x << endl;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Is giving this output:

0
10
45

So, why when "x" is being read is reading the value, but when "x" is modified is modifying the reference target?.

Comment: In this case, in each iteration of the loop, `x` is a reference to an element of `v`.    That's what the `&` in the `auto& v` achieves.    Yes, it is an alias, not a pointer.   You will not be able to compute `*x` (which would be possible if `x` was a pointer), and incrementing `x` in the loop changes elements of `v`.

Comment: It behaves like an alias in the source code. It is of course implemented via a pointer.

Comment: @EJP it **can** be implemented via pointer, there are many cases where pointers are not useful to implement references.

Answer (score 1):

**Consider the following:**

```
int main() {
    int v[] = {0,10,45};

    for (auto x : v) { // Since it's not an alias it doesn't alter `v` array's contents.
        std::cout << ++x << ' '; // Output: 1, 11, 46
    }

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';   // Output: 0, 10, 45 DOES NOT MODIFY v
    }

}
```

**However, if you do this:**

```
int main() {
    int v[] = {0,10,45};

    for (auto& x : v) { // Since it IS an alias it will alter `v` array's contents.
        std::cout << ++x << ' '; // Output: 1, 11, 46
    }

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';   // Output: 1, 11, 46 MODIFIES v
    }        
}
```

See it for [yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fcfb5824b8e12cc).

Comment: Is this the correct answer? Could you upvote and mark as right answer if so?

Answer (score 0):

> So, why when "x" is being read is reading the value, but when "x" is modified is modifying the reference target?

"Modifying the reference target" can be interpreted in two ways, only one of which is correct.  I *think* you're thinking that `x++` advances the reference to refer to the next element in the array, but that's not what it does.  `x++` increments the current element in the array – equivalent to `v[0]++`, `v[1]++`, etc. – but it doesn't affect the output because the number has already been printed.

If you change the loop to:

```
for (auto& x : v) {
    x++;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

you'll get 1, 11, and 46 as output.

Comment: Yes, that was my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So, why when "x" is being read is reading the value, but when "x" is modified is modifying the reference target?.

Because that is what is specified in your `for` statement.

```
for (auto& x : v)
```

As I noted in comment below your question, the `&` specifies that `x` is a reference, and the overall meaning of `for (auto &x : v)` is that `x`, in each iteration of the loop, is a reference to a particular element of `v` (sequentially, from the first to the last).

The compiler takes care of the machinery of changing what `x` refers to for each iteration (e.g. by newly creating `x` at the start of every iteration and destroying it after the loop body is done).

So, in the first iteration, `x` refers to `v[0]`.  So `x++` will increment `v[0]`.   It will not change what `x` refers to, so `x` still refers to `v[0]`.   It will never refer to `v[1]` during the first iteration of the loop.

In the second iteration, `x` refers to `v[1]` (the compiler takes care of that, as I mentioned above).   So `x++` increments `v[1]`, but `x` will still refer to `v[1]`.

And so on, until the end of `v` is detected.

If you change the loop to

```
for (const auto & x : v)
```

you will find that `x++` within the loop body will not compile.   This is because the `const` tells the compiler that `x` is a reference to `const` (i.e. that `x` cannot be used to change the elements of `v`).   `x` will still refer to `v[0]` in the first iteration, but cannot be directly used to change `v[0]`.